# Зачем надо писать typename для уточнения типа?

Tags: c++, c++-faq

При использовании шаблонов иногда надо писать `typename` у типов - когда и зачем это делать?

```
template <class T>
inline void PRINT_ELEMENTS (const T& coll, const char* optcstr="")
{
    typename T::const_iterator pos;

    std::cout << optcstr;
    for (pos=coll.begin(); pos!=coll.end(); ++pos) {
        std::cout << *pos << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @fori1ton: там не аналогичный пример. Насколько я понял, ОП спрашивает зачем в этом коде сделан typename.

Comment: Подробное описание находится по ссылке представленной @fori1ton. Если кратко, то компилятор не знает, что означает `const_iterator`. Синтаксис схож как для переменной, так и для объявления типов (`typedef`). Оператор `typename` говорит, что это имя типа (не переменная).

Comment: @Expert: а что может означать строка ``T::const_iterator pos`` кроме как не объявление типа? Не ``T::const_iterator * pos``, а именно ``T::const_iterator pos``? Компилятор не знает что именно такое T::const_iterator, но что здесь можно предположить как не тип?
Помоему в этом вопрос заключается. Сам я склоняюсь к тому, что это, если не ошибаюсь, требование стандарта.

Comment: @fori1ton, читал ещё давно, но тут же нету звездочки как подметил @fogbit. То есть компилятор не может определить какой тип туда попадет и это делается в рантайм? Но даже если и так, то без typename выйдет же T(тип)::const_iterator(имя переменной) pos(имя переменной), но такое объявление вызовет ошибку. Если есть строчка в стандарте, в которой сказано о необходимости typename в такой ситуации, то зачем она нужна? Ведь компилятор именно в этом случае может и сам справится.

Comment: @Robert Pinkman: непосредственно тип выводится в момент инстанса шаблона в коде, т.е. в compile-time. C шаблонами вообще всё происходит в compile-time, если не ошибаюсь.
Подозреваю что Стандарт не делает различий в ситуациях, а просто декларирует что если есть объявление типа, зависящего от шаблона в любом контексте, то пиши перед ним ``typename``.

Comment: @fogbit, Это может быть ошибка синтаксиса (опечатка). Не уверен, что если убрать `typename` компилятор будет выводить тип. Скорее всего будет синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: @Expert: GCC 4.7.2 ругается, Студия 2003 проглотила и программа отработала как ожидалось - вывела содержимое вектора. Видимо GCC, который сильно позднее вышел, более требователен к соответствию исходников Стандарту.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `T::const_iterator` — *зависимое* имя: оно зависит от параметра шаблона `T`. В этой точке компилятор не знает, каким будет `T`, и не может предсказать, будет ли `T::const_iterator` именем типа или, например, именем статического поля или вообще шаблона. Поэтому он и не пытается угадать, и предполагает, что это поле.

Если же ему подсказать, он будет предполагать, что `T::const_iterator` — это тип, и поймёт, что

```
typename T::const_iterator pos;
```

— объявление переменной.

Почему же компилятор не может подождать с выяснением смысла выражения `T::const_iterator` до того момента, когда тип `T` будет уже известен (то есть, до момента разворачивания шаблона с конкретным типом `T`)? А вот почему: на момент применения шаблона тип `T` имеет право быть ещё не определён! И ещё он может зависеть от самого шаблона. Так что откладывать выяснение смысла выражения нельзя. Пример:

```
template <class T>
class comparable<T>
{
    bool compare(T& other) { return this == other; }
};

class length : public comparable<length> // в этой точке для comparable
                                         // тип T ещё не известен полностью!
{
    ...
```

---

Пример кода, иллюстрирующего «скользкие» моменты, приведён ниже. Он не компилируется gcc (так как нету полагающегося по стандарту `typename`), но более либеральный MSVC 2012 его компилирует и выполняет.

`typename` для того и нужен, чтобы исключить подобные сюрпризы.

```
#include "stdafx.h" // нужно для MSVC
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct A
{
    void f()
    {
        // если T::iterator - тип, это предварительное объявление функции
        // если T::iterator - число, это объявление переменной с инициализацией
        int x(T::iterator);
    }
    void g()
    {
        int x = 5;
        {
            // если T::iterator - шаблон, принимающий числовой аргумент,
            // это инстанциация шаблона в переменную x, перекрывающую x
            // за фигурными скобками
            // если T::iterator -- экземпляр класса с перегруженным оператором <,
            // это сравнение T::iterator с нулём, а затем сравнение результата
            // со значением переменной x!
            T::iterator<0> x;
            // Кто-то всё ещё сомневается, что C++ - непредсказуемый язык?
        }
    }
};

struct T1
{
    typedef int iterator;
};

struct T2
{
    static const int iterator = 5;
};

struct T3
{
    template<int C> struct iterator
    {
        iterator() { cout << "constructing template with C = " << C << endl; }
    };
};

struct T4
{
    struct Titerator
    {
        Titerator operator < (int value)
        {
            cout << "in operator < " << value << endl;
            return Titerator();
        }
        bool operator > (int value)
        {
            cout << "in operator > " <<  value << endl;
            return false;
        }
    };
    static Titerator iterator;
};

T4::Titerator T4::iterator = T4::Titerator();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A<T1> a1; a1.f();
    A<T2> a2; a2.f();
    A<T3> a3; a3.g();
    A<T4> a4; a4.g();
    return 0;
}
```

Результат работы таков:

> `constructing template with C = 0`
> `in operator < 0`
> `in operator > 5`

Comment: Большое спасибо за хорошее прояснение! А могли бы вы ещё привести примеры по этим ситуациями  _курсив_ будет ли T::const_iterator именем типа или, например, именем статического поля или вообще шаблона ?

Comment: @Robert Pinkman: Вот пример кода, иллюстрирующего «скользкие» моменты: http://pastebin.com/Mt1QDV1R Он не компилируется gcc, т.к. отсутствует typename, но MSVC этот код проглатывает, и выдаёт такой результат:

> `constructing template with C = 0`
> `in operator < 0`
> `in operator > 5`

Comment: Спасибо! Все очень доступно, вот только не смог понять за фигурные скобки, потому что первый раз вижу такое употребление фигурных скобок без сигнатуры функции перед ними. Что это такое и почему в итоге перекрывает переменную x, ведь у неё выше уровень и почему нету двойного определения?

Comment: @Robert Pinkman: такие скобки декларируют _блок_ внутри функции. Переменные внутри блока «перекрывают» внешние переменные, и умирают в конце блока. В частности, для объектов, которые были заведены в блоке (не при помощи `new`, а в стеке), будет вызван деструктор.

Comment: То есть нельзя получить доступ к "x" в таком блоке из функции g и вообще никак нельзя?

Comment: @Robert Pinkman: Для кода как в функции `g` я не знаю способа получения доступа к `x` изнутри блока после объявления внутренней переменной. Для `x` объявленного вне функции в некоторых случаях существуют трюки (например, декларация `extern` или расширение области видимости `::x`).