# Класс шаблонного класса не воспринимается как тип при описании метода

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Ругается на этот метод :

```
template <typename T> LinkedList<T>::iterator LinkedList<T>::begin(){
    iterator a(this->head);
    return a;
}
```

Ошибка:

> warning C4346: LinkedList::iterator: зависимое имя не является типом

Предописание класса :

```
template <typename T> class LinkedList{
class Node{
public:
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
    T val;
};
public:
Node *head;
Node *tail;

public:
class iterator {
    Node *node;
    iterator(Node *node);
public:
    //Возвращает ссылку на текущий элемент коллекции.
    T & operator*() const;
    //Возвращает указатель на текущий элемент коллекции.
    T * operator->() const;

    iterator & operator++();
    iterator operator++(int);
    iterator & operator--();
    iterator operator--(int);
};
LinkedList(const LinkedList & other);
~LinkedList();

iterator begin();
}
```

Предописание класса и описание метода лежат в разных файлах, но студия на это конкретно не ругается. перенос описания в файл к предописанию класса не лечит проблему

Comment: В C++ достаточно странный синтаксис. Смиритесь :)

Comment: @VladD в C++ логичный  и строгий синтаксис.

Comment: @zenden2k: Угу, угу. Что означает, по-вашему, конструкция `a && b`?

Comment: @VladD зависит от контекста.

Comment: @zenden2k: Именно! Смысл синтаксической конструкции зависит от семантики окружающего кода.

Comment: @zenden2k: Хуже ужаса, чем «оператор запятая», мне вообще трудно представить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно написать

```
template <typename T>
typename LinkedList<T>::iterator LinkedList<T>::begin()
//^^^^^^
```

Дело в том, что `LinkedList<T>::iterator` — [*зависимое* имя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/239115/10105), поэтому без `typename` не обойтись.

Кроме того, не забудьте, что шаблонные классы нужно (за редкими исключениями) определять полностью в header'е, иначе готовьтесь к ошибкам компоновки.