# определение методов во вложенных шаблонных классах

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
template<class T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
LinkedList(int capacity);
~LinkedList(); 
const LinkedList& operator = (const LinkedList& right);
LinkedList(const LinkedList& right);

class Iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T> 
{
public:
    Iterator(const LinkedList<T> &obj, int index);
    T& operator*();
    Iterator& operator++();
    Iterator& operator--();
    int GetIndex() const { return _copyIndex; };
    int *GetNext() const { return _copyNext; };

 private:
    int _copyIndex;
    int _copyPrevIndex;
    T *_copyItems;
    int *_copyNext;
    int *_copyPrev;
};

Iterator Add(T value);
Iterator Insert(Iterator it, T value);

private:
T *_items;
int *_next;
int *_prev;
int _index;
int _prevIndex;
int _deletedIndex;
int _head;
int _count;
int _capacity;
};
```

вопрос: подскажите пожалуста как вынести определение методов в классе Iterator и методов которые возвращают итератор из класса LinkedList?

Answer (score 0):

Методы класса `LinkedList<T>::Iterator`:

```
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::Iterator::Iterator(const LinkedList<T>& obj, int index)
{
     // ...
}

template <class T>
T& LinkedList<T>::Iterator::operator*()
{
    // ...
}

template <class T>
typename LinkedList<T>::Iterator& LinkedList<T>::Iterator::operator++()
{
    // ...
}

template <class T>
typename LinkedList<T>::Iterator& LinkedList<T>::Iterator::operator--()
{
    // ...
}

template <class T>
int LinkedList<T>::Iterator::GetIndex() const
{
    // ...
}

template <class T>
int* LinkedList<T>::Iterator::GetNext() const
{
    // ...
}
```

Методы класса `LinkedList<T>`, возращающие экземпляры `LinkedList<T>::Iterator`:

```
template <class T>
typename LinkedList<T>::Iterator LinkedList<T>::Add(T value)
{
    // ...
}

template <class T>
typename LinkedList<T>::Iterator LinkedList<T>::Insert(Iterator it, T value)
{
    // ...
}
```

Для чего необходимо дополнительное ключевое слово `typename` при обращении к типу `LinkedList<T>::Iterator`, можно прочитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/239051/272980).