# Как создать template который наследует от класса (JAVA, CPP)?

Tags: java, c++, шаблоны-с++, generics

Хочу понять есть ли возможность в `cpp` сделать чтоб дженерик тип наследовал какой то класс(так как нет интерфейсов в `cpp`), чтоб получилось вот так как в джава

```
public interface IReleasable
{
    void release();
}

public class A<TYPE extends IReleasable>
{
    void foo(TYPE iObj)
    {
        iObj.release();
    }
}
```

То есть я знаю точно, что обьект который будет мне подаваться в качестве типа будет иметь нужный мне метод

Как это сделать в `cpp`?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, в вашем примере generic не нужен, можно в foo сразу принимать объект типа IReleasable. 
Но вот мой пример для C++ через std::enable_if

```
#include <iostream>

class IReleasable {
public:
    virtual void release() = 0;
    virtual ~IReleasable(){}
};


class Release : public IReleasable {
public:
    void release() override {
        std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    }
};

//class E = void для проверки условия через std::enable_if
template <class  T, class E = void> class A;

//частичная спецализация только для наследников IReleasable
template <class T>
class A<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<IReleasable, T>>> {
public:
    void foo(T& iObj) {
        iObj.release();
    }
};

int main() {
    Release r1;
    Release r2;
    IReleasable &ir = r2;

    A<IReleasable> a1;
    a1.foo(r1);
    a1.foo(ir);

    //A<int> a2; //ошибка компиляции
    //A<string> a3; //ошибка компиляции
}
```

Для С++11

```
template <class T>
class A<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<IReleasable, T>::value>::type> {
public:
    void foo(T& iObj) {
        iObj.release();
    }
};
```

Comment: Выглядит очень не плохо, только у меня почему то не доступно `enable_if_t` и `is_base_of_v` хотя есть вот такие типы `enable_if` и `is_base_of` , это точно не ошибка?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Для `enable_if_t` нужен C++14, для `is_base_of_v` нужен C++17. Для С++11 это будет выглядеть так `typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<IReleasable, T>::value>::type`

Comment: Можете это добавить в отвтет? А то я не сильно пойму куда писать `typename`

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko добавил. Так же можете посмотреть [Зачем надо писать typename для уточнения типа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/239051/276430)

Answer (score 0):

В C++ нет дженериков, в C++ есть шаблоны. Это две принципиально разные вещи. Однако, в C++ есть инструменты, чтобы с помощью шаблонной магии отсекать ненужные типы. Вам пригодится [проверка наличия функции в классе](http://scrutator.me/post/2017/04/10/has_function_metaprogramming.aspx), с последующим отклонением всех типов, которые не подходят с помощью [SFINAE](http://scrutator.me/post/2016/12/12/sfinae.aspx). Обе ссылки на мои статьи, чтобы разобраться в теме, но тема достаточно сложная для новичка в C++. Поэтому я не уверен, что Вы действительно хотите сейчас погружаться в эти дебри.

Тем не менее если всё-таки упорство победит и Вам действительно это нужно, то, разобравшись с основами, обратите внимание на библиотеку [Boost.Hana](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html) — в ней содержится много вещей, которые, в том числе, будут полезными для упрощения определения наличия функции у того или иного типа. Это очень богатая библиотека.

Наконец, в будущих версиях С++ (начиная с C++20) появятся концепции, которые в некоторой степени упростят подобные задачи. Т.е. шаблонная магия никуда не денется, но синтаксис станет проще и решение подобной задачи будет выглядеть примерно так же, как это выглядит в Java/C#.

---

Можно, конечно, воспользоваться несколько более грубым решением: совместить чистые виртуальные функции с шаблоном. В этом случае мы можем легко убедиться, что наш класс-аргумент наследуется от этого класса и этого будет достаточно, чтобы убедиться в наличии реализации методов. Выглядеть будет примерно так:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct IReleasable
{
    virtual void release() = 0;
};

template <typename Releasable>
struct A
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<IReleasable, Releasable>, "Should inherit IReleasable");

    void foo(Releasable iObj)
    {
        iObj.release();
    }
};

struct Rel: IReleasable
{
    void release() override
    {}
};

struct NoRel 
{
    void release()
    {}
};
int main()
{
    A<Rel> rel;
    A<NoRel> norel;
    return 0;
}
```

Недостатки очевидны: нужно выстраивать иерархию, использовать виртуальные функции, а также никакого Duck Typing. И, в конце концов, какой тогда смысл с шаблонного параметра, когда всё равно всё свелось к иерархии классов и основному интерфейсу? Можно тогда вообще без шаблона обойтись. Но для грубого решения этого может быть достаточно.

Answer (score -1):

Абстрактный класс вместо интерфейса с одним объявленным методом

```
class IReleasable {
public:
    virtual void release() = 0;
};
```

Наследуем этот класс и определяем метод

```
class Release: public IReleasable {
public:
    void release() override {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

шаблон

```
template<class T>
class A {
public:
    void foo(T r)
    {
        r.release();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A<Release> a;
    Release r;
    a.foo(r); //hello
}
```

Comment: Чет я не совсем понимаю, а как компилятор поймет, что `template<class T>` , что `T` это обьект типа `IRelease`? Если я сделаю так `A<MyAnotherClass> a;` и этот класс не будет содержать реализацию `IReleasalbe` то что тогда будет?

Comment: Не скомпилируется. Release подставляется вместо T на этапе компиляции, в результате инстанциируется новый тип A<Release>, и если у Release не объявлен или не определен метод release, то и соответственно код не скомпилится

Comment: это логично... Потому, что в вашем примере ошибка. Как в этом методе `void foo(T r)` я могу быть уверен, что тип `T` содержит метод `r.release();`? я с таким же успехом могу написать `r.helloMyFriend();` который даже не существует... по ващей логике это так, верно?

Comment: В моем джава примере я говорю, что `TYPE extend IReleasable` таким образом компилятор знает, что любой класс который подается в качестве типа имплементирует `IReleasable`, а у него есть метод `release();` значит это законно написать `r.release()` так как я уверен, что тип содержит этот метод, но в вашем примере этой связи нет...

Comment: У вас компилируется мой пример с  `r.helloMyFriend()?`

Comment: Я не пробовал так как выглядит не логично. Или вы настаиваете, что это верный путь сделать это? Ок, я сейчас попробую