# Обратиться к псевдониму типа в определении метода вне класса

Tags: c++

Составил небольшой пример. Компилятор не может найти тип *ref* как возвращаемое значение метода *getA()* . Почему это происходит? И как тогда лучше писать? Спасибо.

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    T a;
public:
    using ref = const T&;

    ref getA()const;
};

template<class T>
A<T>::ref A<T>::getA() const
{
    return a;
}
```

Comment: нужно добавить typename, т.е. 
`typename A<T>::ref `[Зачем надо писать typename для уточнения типа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/239051/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-typename-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0), но т.к. это не очень удобно, то проще написать `const T&`

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon огромное спасибо, действительно, компилятор ведь ещё не знает, что это будет за тип. Ещё раз благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае без указания `typename` компилятор воспринимает зависимое имя `ref` не как имя типа. Однако использовать `typename` в данном случае совсем не обязательно, так как это имя может быть найдено в контексте этого класса. Проще и короче будет использовать  хвостовой синтаксис для возвращаемого значения, это также позволит избавиться от `A<T>::`.

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    T a;
public:
    using ref = const T&;

    ref getA()const;
};

template<class T> auto
A<T>::getA() const -> ref
{
    return a;
}
```