# Простой шаблонный класс и итератор

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь сделать простейший шаблонный класс, но, что то у меня возникала проблема. Вот простейший шаблонный класс:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

    template <typename my_type>
    
    class my_class
    {
    
    public:
    
    
        int summ(my_type my_type_)
        {
            my_int = my_int + my_type_;
    
            std::cout << my_int;
    
            return my_int;
        }
    
    private:
    
        int my_int=0;
    
        std::deque<my_type>my_deque;
    };
```

Все нормально работает, компилируется. Но, как только я добавляю в секцию private:

```
std::deque<my_type>::iterator my_deq_iter;
```

То уже ничего не работает и сообщается о синтаксической ошибке:

> Ошибка    C2061   синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "iterator"

> Ошибка    C2238   непредвиденные лексемы перед ";"

Но, если я уберу шаблоны и будут прост использовать using my_type, вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

    class my_class
    {
    
      using my_type = int;  
    
    public:
    
    
        int summ(my_type my_type_)
        {
            my_int = my_int + my_type_;
    
            std::cout << my_int;
    
            return my_int;
        }
    
    private:
    
        int my_int=0;
    
        std::deque<my_type>my_deque;
    
        std::deque<my_type>::iterator my_deq_iter;    //Теперь все работает.
    
    };
```

То все работает.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так во взаимодействии шаблонов и итератора ?

Comment: Имя `std::deque<my_type>::iterator` неявно зависит от параметра шаблона https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name.  Поэтому, нужен typename: `typename std::deque<my_type>::iterator my_deq_iter;` см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/239051/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-typename-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0

Comment: @Chorkov Только оно зависит *явно*.